# c# Method override. How to call it correctly

Tags: c#, .net

learning c #, and trying to write a post search

in this code everything worked out for me:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace _3._1
{
    class Program {
        static void Main(){
            List<Message> messages = new List<Message>();

            messages.Add(new SmsMessage {text = "Hello!"});
            messages.Add(new SmsMessage {text = "What?"});
            messages.Add(new SmsMessage {text = "You?"});
            
            messages.Add(new EmailMessage {text = "Show"});
            messages.Add(new EmailMessage {text = "You!"});
            messages.Add(new EmailMessage {text = "Hello!"});


            string query = Console.ReadLine();
            int i = 0;
            foreach(Message str in messages){
                if(Message.Search(str, query)){
                    i++;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"query: {query} | coincidences: {i}");
        }
    }
    class Message {
        public string text { get; set; }
        public static bool Search(Message message, string query){
            if(message.text.Contains(query))return true;
            return false;
        }
    }
    class SmsMessage : Message {
        public string phone;
    }
    class EmailMessage : Message {
        public string email;
        public string subject;
    }
}
```

but how can you override the Search method on Virtual, and reassign it in other classes so that the search works the same as before?

Answer (score 2):

`static` members could not be `virtual` and thus could not be overridden.
In your case looks like you can make your `Search` method non static and then `virtual`

```
class Message {
    public string text { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Search(string query){
        if(this.text.Contains(query))return true;
        return false;
    }
}
class SmsMessage : Message {
    public string phone;
    public virtual bool Search(string query){
            //search code here;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to override method, it cannot be `static` (static methods could not be overridden) and have to be virtual. So remove the `static` keyword in your search method definition and make the method `virtual`.

```
  class Message {
    public string text { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Search(Message message, string query){
        if(message.text.Contains(query))return true;
        return false;
     }
   }

  class SmsMessage : Message {
    public string phone;
    public override bool Search(Message message, string query) {
       // do something
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the method in the base class with the virtual keyword, then implement the method in the child classes with the override keyword